# Document storage models and Django Unit Testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, django

My question is about proper testing procedures for Django models.
The project is for a startup building a very basic HR system due to excel sheet data integrity problems. I am trying to figure out the best way to unit test the documents and models they will be managing.

Based on how I wrote this test, what are some ways I could make it better?
I will be writing 8 more tests like this so don't want to repeat any mistakes due to ignorance.

Models:

```py
class Passport(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    issue_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    expiration_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
    dob = models.DateField()
    "https://pypi.org/project/django-countries/"
    place_of_issue = CountryField(blank=False,null=True)
    #place_of_issue = models.CharField(_("Country code as displayed in passport"),max_length=5)
    image = models.ImageField(storage=PrivateMediaStorage(), upload_to='passports')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Employee: {self.owner.first_name}"





class Employee(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    employment_statuses = (
        ('ap','Applicant'),
        ('trial', 'Initial Training'),
        ('em', 'Employed'),
        ('ps','Pause')
    )
    genders = (('M', 'male'),('F', 'female'))
    # core information
    full_name = models.CharField(_('Surname, Given Names as on passport'), validators=[name_validator], max_length=25, blank=False, null=True)

    #employment data
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=genders)
    employee_id_code = models.CharField(_('employee id number'),max_length=20, null=True)

    # activity Status
    employment_status = models.CharField(choices=employment_statuses, max_length=30)
    employment_status_note = models.TextField(max_length=500)


    # contact information
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('-redacted- email address'), unique=True)
    personal_email = models.EmailField(_('Personal Email Address'), unique=True)


    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def first_name(self):
        try:
            return str(self.full_name.split()[1])
        except:
            pass
    def middle_name(self):
        try:
            return str(self.full_name.split()[2])
        except:
            pass
    def last_name(self):
        try:
            return str(self.full_name.split()[0])
        except:
            pass

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.full_name} {self.email}"
```

Testing Code (test_passport.py) in testing module in the documents app

```py
    import faker
    from django.test import TestCase
    from core_hr.models import Passport
    from users.models import Employee
    from django_countries.fields import CountryField
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    import random
    fake = faker.Faker()

    def get_mock_user():
        full_name = f"{fake.first_name()} {fake.last_name()} {fake.last_name()}"
        gender = random.choice([x[0] for x in Employee.genders])
        employee_id_code =f"G-{fake.ean8()}"

        employment_status = random.choice([x[0] for x in Employee.employment_statuses])
        employment_status_note = fake.bs()

        phone_number = fake.phone_number()
        email = fake.email()
        personal_email = fake.email()
        date_joined = fake.past_date(start_date="-120d", tzinfo=None)
        user = Employee.objects.create_user(
            full_name=full_name,
            gender=gender,
            employee_id_code=employee_id_code,
            employment_status=employment_status,
            employment_status_note= employment_status_note,
            phone_number=phone_number,
            personal_email=personal_email,
            date_joined=date_joined,
            email=email,
            password='foo'
        )

        return user

    def get_mock_passport(employee):
        owner = Employee.objects.get(id=employee.id)
        dob = fake.date_between(start_date="-9y", end_date="-1m")
        date_of_expiration = fake.date_between(start_date="+3m", end_date="+9y")
        place_of_issue = fake.country_code()
        date_of_issue = fake.date_between(start_date="-9y", end_date="-1m")
        passport = Passport.objects.create(
            owner=owner,
            place_of_issue=place_of_issue,
            issue_date=date_of_issue,
            expiration_date=date_of_expiration,
            dob=dob
        )
        return passport

    class PassportTestCase(TestCase):

        def setUp(self):
            self.employee = get_mock_user()
            self.passport = get_mock_passport(self.employee)

        def test_passport_has_fields(self):
            retrieved_passport = Passport.objects.get(id=self.passport.pk)
            self.assertEqual(self.passport, retrieved_passport)
```